# MYSQL Insert: How to save Query in the database only one time - duplicate key doesn't work!

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to save a query only one time in the database, this is my code:

```
   $querystat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
    $datetime = time();
    if( ($querystat != $_SESSION['prev_search']) OR ( ($datetime - $_SESSION['datetime']) > 60) ) {
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO `query` ( `searchquery` , `datetime`) VALUES ( '$querystat' , '$datetime') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE searchquery='$querystat';";
    mysql_query($insertquery, $db);
    }
```

maybe something with `== 0` ?

Comment: dont know where to put the ==0 in my code.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is by `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you are checking if there was a duplicate on key 1, `id`. What you are trying to have is unique values for field `searchquery`. You will need to create a UNIQUE index on field `searchquery`. To do that, run `ALTER TABLE query ADD UNIQUE ( searchquery )`. 
However, what `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part of your query does is probably not what you want. To indicate that this query was repeated at a later time, you probably would want to do `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datetime='$datetime'`

Also, are you sure you need field `id` at all?

Comment: no dont need it, but should I delete the double entries before running this query?

Comment: Yes, you certainly must do so.

Answer (score 0):

Is field searchquery UNIQUE or PRIMARY_KEY?

Comment: dont know, this was the query: CREATE TABLE `query` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`searchquery` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`datetime` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM